# Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in '[...]\node_modules\follow-redirects'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

While building the app, I encounter the warning from 3rd party lib as below:

```
warn  - ./node_modules/follow-redirects/debug.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in 'G:\Workspace\node\MERN\client\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './debug'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).    
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
```

My stack :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "mdb-ui-kit": "^6.0.1",
    "next": "^13.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1"
  }
```

Content of the debug.js within follow-redirects:

```
var debug;

module.exports = function () {
  if (!debug) {
    try {
      /* eslint global-require: off */
      debug = require("debug")("follow-redirects");
    }
    catch (error) { /* */ }
    if (typeof debug !== "function") {
      debug = function () { /* */ };
    }
  }
  debug.apply(null, arguments);
};
```

And import within index.js file:

```
var url = require("url");
var URL = url.URL;
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
var Writable = require("stream").Writable;
var assert = require("assert");
var debug = require("./debug");
```

I've checked they repo and issues but apparently no one has ever reported it so I wonder whether it has to do with my specific setup?

I've also tried to remove node_modules and reinstall all dependencies via npm with no luck.

Answer (score 5):

This is normal behavior for the `follow-redirects` package.

The `debug.js` file does the following:

- attempts to load the `debug` npm package.
- catches the error for it not being found.
- assigns an empty function to the `debug` variable.

The code was designed to work with the `debug` npm package for NodeJs, but this was intended to be optional.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

Problems:

- the use of the word `debug` repeatedly around the code is confusing. There are 3 different debug references, the `debug.js` file in the `follow-redirects`, the `debug` module variable within that file and the `debug` npm package (that is not installed).

The `follows-redirect` lists `debug` as an optional peer dependency:

```
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "debug": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
```

The warning you see:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in 'G:\Workspace\node\MERN\client\node_modules\follow-redirects'
```

Is from NextJs and it's being reported for compiling the *server side* code because it seems like a failure of NodeJs to resolve the package.

How `follow-redirects` checks for the use of the `debug` package is a code smell. It should be a user configurable feature, and not something forced on just because a npm package was installed as a peer dependency, or lazy require() and catching an error.

You have the option to install debug and use the feature which fixes the warning.

```
npm install debug
```

Alternatively, just ignore the warning. There is no harm in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this line `debug = require("debug")("follow-redirects");` should be
`debug = require("./debug")("follow-redirects");`

Answer (score 0):

Delete json.lock and then run npm install after deleting node modules.

Answer (score -1):

Main Issue: While building an app, a warning was encountered from a 3rd party library "follow-redirects" that it cannot resolve "debug" module in a particular directory, leading to failure in resolving requests.

The warning is caused by "follow-redirects" module's inability to resolve the "debug" module in the specified directory.
The issue can be resolved by changing the source code or by using the "preferRelative" resolve option to resolve the requests in the current directory.
The attempt to remove node_modules and reinstall all dependencies via npm did not resolve the issue.
Keywords:

follow-redirects module
debug module
resolving requests
preferRelative resolve option
reinstalling dependencies.
Clickable links:

follow-redirects module
debug module
resolving requests
preferRelative resolve option
reinstalling dependencies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).